# PHP converting an array of strings to a two-dimensional array with custom keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new in PHP and have to convert data from a JS array, which I read from a text file, to a PHP array.
So far, after file reading and some "cleaning" and sorting, I have the following array of strings:

```
$workArray[0] = "\"20180125_0363\",\"363\",\"25.01.2018\",\"Some long text here\",false,\"\"";
$workArray[1] = "\"20180125_0364\",\"364\",\"25.01.2018\",\"Some long text here\",true,\"Some short text here\"";
$workArray[2] = "\"20180125_0365\",\"365\",\"25.01.2018\",\"Some long text here\",true,\"Some short text here\"";
...
...
etc.
```

I need some help with the following task: How to convert the **$workArray** to a two-dimensional **$dataArray** array, whose elements are arrays with custom keys, and values, extracted from above strings?

```
$dataArray[0] = array(
    "uid"       => "20180125_0363",
    "number"    => "363",
    "date"      => "25.01.2018",
    "title"     => "Some long text here",
    "docFlag"   => false,
    "docTitle"  => ""
);

$dataArray[1] = array(
    "uid"       => "20180125_0364",
    "number"    => "364",
    "date"      => "25.01.2018",
    "title"     => "Some long text here",
    "docFlag"   => true,
    "docTitle"  => "Some short text here"
);

$dataArray[2] = array(
    "uid"       => "20180125_0365",
    "number"    => "365",
    "date"      => "25.01.2018",
    "title"     => "Some long text here",
    "docFlag"   => true,
    "docTitle"  => "Some short text here"
);

...
...
etc.
```

Comment: Did you try it by yourself or you are asking someone to make it for you? Just as a tip you can use `for` and `foreach` to iterate over arrays.

Comment: @MikeVelazco I tried several different ways in the last 4 hours without success. I needed a guidance in the right direction, not someone to do it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the keys in an array, then use [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to explode each element into an array, and finally use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to pair the keys and the values:

```
<?php
$keys = [
    "uid",
    "number",
    "date",
    "title",
    "docFlag",
    "docTitle",
];
$workArray[0] = "\"20180125_0364\",\"363\",\"25.01.2018\",\"Some long text here\",false,\"\"";
$workArray[1] = "\"20180125_0363\",\"364\",\"25.01.2018\",\"Some long text here\",true,\"Some short text here\"";
$workArray[2] = "\"20180125_0358\",\"365\",\"25.01.2018\",\"Some long text here\",true,\"Some short text here\"";
foreach ($workArray as &$el) {
    $values = str_getcsv($el);
    $el = array_combine($keys, $values);
}
var_dump($workArray);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Fn2G6)

Note that each element is [passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) so as to modify each element itself and not a copy.

Or, a little more elegant, use [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to apply a function to each element in the array. Again, the element is passed by reference, and [`use()`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#functions.anonymous) is used to bring the `$keys` array into the scope of the anonymous function:

```
array_walk($workArray, function(&$el) use($keys) {
    $values = str_getcsv($el);
    $el = array_combine($keys, $values);
});
```

*Result*

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'uid' => string '20180125_0364' (length=13)
      'number' => string '363' (length=3)
      'date' => string '25.01.2018' (length=10)
      'title' => string 'Some long text here' (length=19)
      'docFlag' => string 'false' (length=5)
      'docTitle' => string '' (length=0)
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      'uid' => string '20180125_0363' (length=13)
      'number' => string '364' (length=3)
      'date' => string '25.01.2018' (length=10)
      'title' => string 'Some long text here' (length=19)
      'docFlag' => string 'true' (length=4)
      'docTitle' => string 'Some short text here' (length=20)
  2 => 
    array (size=6)
      'uid' => string '20180125_0358' (length=13)
      'number' => string '365' (length=3)
      'date' => string '25.01.2018' (length=10)
      'title' => string 'Some long text here' (length=19)
      'docFlag' => string 'true' (length=4)
      'docTitle' => string 'Some short text here' (length=20)
```